# Revealing module pattern got undefined variable

Tags: javascript

Just starting to take javascript seriously. What is wrong with my code below?

```
var Person = (function(name,age){
   var name = name, age = age;
   var print = function(){
      console.log('I"m '+name+', and I"m '+age+' year old');
   }

   return {print:print}
})();

Person.print("James",19);
```

I got name and age undefined. I problem i found also with this pattern, if u have many method then in the end your return will be

`return {methodA:methodA, methodB:methodB, methodC:methodC}` this is so ugly for me. Should I just wrap my method within the return like

```
return{ 
  methodA: function(){

  } 
};
```

Comment: Not the problem, but note that the line `var name = name, age = age;` could be removed with no change in behaviour - the function arguments are already part of the closure, so there's no need to try to copy them to local variables, and trying to create a local variable with the same name as a function argument doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments to your method, you should put them in your `print` function, like so.

```js
var Person = (function(){
   var print = function(name,age){
      console.log('I"m '+name+', and I"m '+age+' year old');
   }

   return {print:print}
})();

Person.print("James",19);
```

Alternately, you might be trying to pass the arguments into your IIFE directly, but I'm not sure I see the point in doing that if that is the case.

```js
var Person = (function(name,age){
   var print = function(){
      console.log('I"m '+name+', and I"m '+age+' year old');
   }

   return {print:print}
})("James",19);

Person.print();
```

Yes, you could just return your methods on the object, but that would not technically be revealing module pattern.

```js
var Person = (function(){
   return {
       print: function(name,age){
           console.log('I"m '+name+', and I"m '+age+' year old');
       }
   }
})();

Person.print("James",19);
```

Personally, if you really want to get into modern JavaScript, I'd recommend ES6 modules or CommonJS modules, with a builder like Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: ah I got it, let function print recieve the param instead of the Person obj. I got it! But is this revealing module pattern? I remember there are private variable within Person object for encapsulation.

Comment: @JessJordan Yes, you can have private variables and functions inside that closure. Just don't return them.

Comment: ES6 modules have to do with webpack?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of [Immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Here you go Fixed snippet.

```js
var Person = (function(name,age){
   var name = name, age = age;
   var print = function(){
      console.log('I"m '+name+', and I"m '+age+' year old');
   }

   return {print:print}
})("James",19);

Person.print();
```

Comment: this is not flexible at all, how can my Person be dynamic then?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, make name and age shared variable

```js
var Person = (function(name,age){
    var name = name, age = age;
  
    var print = function(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        console.log('I"m '+this.name+', and I"m '+this.age+' year old');
      }
  return {print:print}
})();

Person.print("James",19);
```